# Can I compare different estimations approaches with AIC?

Tags: regression, panel-data, aic, diagnostic

I'm running two different panel models.

- Model 1 is a Random Effects regression estimated using Maximum Likelihood and bootstrapped standard errors.
- Model 2 has the same main dependent variables and regressors, but is estimated using a spatial panel package (xsmle in Stata) with Driscoll-Kraay standard errors (which are in turn based on Newey-West, 1987).

Can I compare these models using AIC?

Because I can't get post-estimation plots after panel regression (i.e., residual-versus-fitted plots and added variable plots) it seems like I need to run a pooled OLS regression. Is this the correct approach to assessing normality of the errors after a panel model?

Comment: I was thinking if not AIC be the same for both models, as both have the same number of explanatory variables and the maximum likelihood value would be not affected by the choice of variance estimator?

Comment: here's a nice reading about AIC and its uses http://warnercnr.colostate.edu/~anderson/PDF_files/AIC%20Myths%20and%20Misunderstandings.pdf